# PHP != and == operators

Tags: php

This has boggled me for a while. I am running through a directory and echo'ing out its contents, and I want to exclude the ".." and "." files.

Now, this code works:

```
if ($files = scandir("temp/"))
{
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if ($file == ".." OR $file == ".")
        {
        }
        else {
            echo $file;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't...

```
if ($files = scandir("temp/"))
{
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if ($file != ".." OR $file != ".")
        {
            echo $file;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

For obvious reasons the second lump of code is more what I want, because I really hate having the true statement do nothing.

Comment: You really need to choose an accepted answer on some your questions.

Answer (score 22):

If you negate a condition consisting of two single conditions and a conjunction ("and" or "or"), you need to negate each condition separately and use the other conjunction.

So try this instead:

```
if ($file != ".." AND $file != ".")
```

Answer (score 9):

This is one of [deMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
not (A OR B) = (not A) AND (not B)
```

The change you are making is a [refactoring](http://www.refactoring.com/) called [Reverse Conditional](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/reverseConditional.html)

Answer (score 4):

They're not opposites...

[Check out de Morgan's laws.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if($file != ".." OR $file != ".")
```

should be

```
if($file != ".." AND $file != ".")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to negate the entire expression, just like `-(-x + 2)` in math negates *everything*:

```
if ($file == ".." OR $file == ".")
```

Is not the negation of

```
if ($file != ".." OR $file != ".")
```

Because you didn't negate the OR. The opposite of OR is AND, resulting a:

```
if ($file != ".." AND $file != ".")
```

Answer (score 2):

`$file != ".."` evaluates to true. Instead, simply use an AND operator:

```
if ( $file != '..' && $file != '.' ) { }
```

However, I would use DirectoryIterator instead:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('temp') as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot())
        continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    if ($file != ".." OR $file != ".")
```

should be:

```
    if ($file != ".." && $file != ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could always use [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/directoryiterator) and specifically its [isDot](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.isdot.php) method.